# Bode plot finding K

Tags: transfer-function, bode-plot

I have no issue finding a and b. However to find K, I would like to know if I'm taking the right approach. I found $$a = 1/24$$ and  $$b = 4$$
So how I'm planning on calculating K is as followed:
$$2k/a = 8$$
since $$a = 1/24$$ then 
$$k = 1/6$$ 
Am I right? if not, please explain why this approach is wrong. 
Thank you. 
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be unrelated to electronics design

Comment: Where did you get the 8 for (2K/a) = 8  from?
I'm pritty sure you shouldn't include the a. It's because your trasfer cunion should be normalized in the form of (s/a),(s/b). Then you take 20log(constant), which in your case 20log(2K) and determine where the graph starts from.

Comment: @ChetanBhargava drawing bode plots is quite a basic EE thing actually.

Comment: @VladimirCravero more towards mathematical side if you agree.

Comment: Yeah you are right of course, I just think that such a question can fit this site better than mathematics.se.com because bode plots are heavily used in EE. And I think that OP is studying EE so that's why she came here.

Comment: @ChetanBhargava Arguing over whether this question is related to EE or not, while we know it is, is a waste of time.

Comment: "By signing this document, you are pledging to adhere to the honor system stating that all work performed here is strictly your own effort", the irony is too much for me.

Comment: @hesson To ease the irony for you, it's an old practice quiz. If it was otherwise, I could just simply crop out the top part.

Comment: @VladimirCravero Thank you for your response. Your answer seems correct to me. :)

Comment: @ShidehNaderi Fair enough :)

Comment: @ShidehNaderi you can vote up or down an answer if you think it's correct (or not), and if you are the asker you can choose one answer between all the given ones.

Comment: @VladimirCravero I'm aware, however I can't upvote since I don't have 15 reputation points yet.

Comment: @ShidehNaderi very good, I thought you were quite new here since you only have 3 rep, I don't really know the rules though.

Comment: @VladimirCravero Been a long time lurker,although I recently decided to actually join SE. :)

Comment: @ShidehNaderi have you passed your final? Ready to contribute to SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations to find a and b looks good to me but I don't agree on K.

You are given only the "unity frequency" or better "unity pulsation" (hope that's correct in English). You should take your transfer function and approximate it appropriately, then fill in the informations you have, i.e. at pulsation 8 gain is 1. The TF you are looking for is the TF stripped of all its poles and zeroes except the "origin pole" (again, hope that's correct), i.e.:
$$G(s)=\frac{2K}{s}$$
that's because you are assuming \$s\ll s_l\$ where \$s_l\$ is the lowest singularity. Solving the previou equation for k:
$$K=\frac{s\cdot G(s)}{2}=\frac{8\cdot 1}{2} = 4$$
that's about 12dB.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any values on the y axis, how did you know that the gain is 1 at pulstation 8?

Comment: I am assuming that the pulsation axis is located at 0dB as it usually is, and as you can see (it took a while for me) the first slope is prolonged till the axis so the gain is one at pulsation 8 *only for the approximate* transfer function.

Comment: Sweet! I got another misconception now, why did you determine that the magnitude at s=8 is the same at the beginning of the graph. I mean why did you take s=8?
I'm asking because I can see the 20bd/decade between s=4 and s=8, which is ((8-4)/10 *20) = 8 db increment. This can never equal to the -20db/decade for s=1 to s=2 which has a 2db increment.

Comment: That is not the same. Look closely at my calculations, my G(s) expression contains an s so it is pulsation dependant. And there's no beginning of the graph on a bode plot...

Comment: Sorry, was confused for some time. The "there's no beginning of the graph on a bode plot" got me on the track, I was completely missing that part. Thanks!